# Kernel Sources for Micromax A87/ Qualcomm MSM7627A

Tags: android

I am completely new to Building from Source in Android. I know Java but that's the limit of my knowledge. Have been using Ubuntu Linux for years now and I have built a couple of small software from source for Linux. But... something tells me Android is going to be completely different.

Firstly, my phone is the Micromax A87 which is a rebrand of the Mito A78 and the *ro.product.device* is *MSM7627A* which belongs in the Snapdragon S1 family. My first goal is to build a working ICS/Honeycomb for this phone and then, maybe, CyanogenMod. Reading through some articles taught me that building ICS/CM for the A87 is gonna be hard because Micromax didn't release the Kernel Sources. But then, I tripped on the CodeAurora for MSM7627A and a GitHub Search for MSM7627A shows some 3-4 results which seem relevant. Also looking in CyanogenMod's Git, I tripped on Hardware sources for qualcomm phones.

By now, I am completely confused and puzzled. So here are my questions:

Which one should I choose? The CyanogenMod one or the others in GitHub?
Can somebody link me to a guide or give me a quick walkthrough on how to build Android from source?

Thank You, My Dear Developers!

I copy-pasted the build.prop here:

```
ro.build.id=GINGERBREAD
ro.build.display.id=LQAEB28.1.0_W120818
ro.build.custom.internal.id=LQAEB28.1.0_W120818
ro.build.custom.internal.name=Micromax  
ro.build.display.ctaversion=
ro.build.version.incremental=LQAEB28.1.0_MG19
ro.build.version.sdk=10
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=2.3.5
ro.build.version.internal=LQAEB28_10982303_0.0.7W0818_A
ro.build.version.external=LQAEB28.1.1_MG19
ro.build.display.hardware=MG19
ro.build.display.ctaversion=
ro.build.hardware.platform=aw735_pcb
ro.build.wifi.brand=atheros
ro.build.bluetooth.brand=qualcomm
ro.build.internal.type=NORMAL
ro.build.network.type=wcdma_gsm
ro.build.operator.name= 
ro.build.extstorage.type=SDCARD
ro.product.proximity.brand=none
ro.build.gy.id=
ro.build.date=2012年 08月 18日 星期六 17:38:55 CST
ro.build.date.utc=1345282735
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=shenweixing
ro.build.host=ibusoft57
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.product.model=Micromax A87
ro.product.brand=Micromax
ro.product.name=A87
ro.product.device=msm7627a
ro.product.ctsdevice=A87
ro.product.board=msm7627a
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=Micromax
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
ro.board.platform=msm7k
```

Comment: Since you are new to this, perhaps first start with the one that has the best build instructions.  Then once you've been through the process, start thinking about what aspects would make it best fit your device.  See if your device has a /proc/config.gz which will give you some clues about the kernel used.  But you'll likely need various proprietary drivers for which you don't have source...

Comment: @ChrisStratton - There IS a config.gz. I just requested the manufacturer to release the source code. Say, Isn't not releasing the source code a violation of the Android License, I read about it from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO http://forums.droidbeans.com/developer-guides/kernel-sources-for-msm7627a/
This is the right one and please do inform ( on that forum :droidbeans ) if and when it's completed

Comment: Rolled back to the original author's version.  Where a link is the bulk of the answer, it's helpful to have the link target immediately visible as an aid to judging its relevance and provenance - hiding it becomes counterproductive.